# PhoneGap audio lag

Tags: cordova, phonegap

I use javascript to play a short sound on my app:

```
var audio = new Audio('sound.mp3');
audio.play();
```

When the above code is called, the whole app gets a lag/delay. After about 200-500ms the app continues as normal and plays the sound. After playing the sound for 2-3 times it seems to have cached or something, because then it works as it should without a lag.

This happens when testing in PhoneGap app for iOS. Running in Chrome desktop it works good.

Comment: Maybe the phone you're testing on is slow?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may consider loading the sound when you app is launched and keep it in the cache. Then, just play it when needed. That should reduce the lap or even omit it.

Comment: Thanks. I havent found a good solution to load a sound to the cache so I can try, do you know how?

Comment: This plugin may be very helpful: https://github.com/floatinghotpot/cordova-plugin-nativeaudio

Answer (score 0):

Basically, the 200-500 ms delay is not a bug or a performance issue, it's a feature necessary to detect the possible double tap.

The solution to get rid of that delay is:

1) To use a combination of touch events instead of the click event, Or

2) Touse fastClick if you don't have jQuery Mobile.

3) If fastclick doesn't work, use this:

```
      $('yourElement').on( 'touchstart', function ( startEvent ) {});
```

Comment: I already use fastclick and touchstart. This doesn't just happen on touchstart, the lag occurs when the audio plays without any touching too.

Comment: That might be the issue with App cache. Try to play with that too. That might help.

Comment: I think the soultion is what you said. The sounds need to be chached before playing. Loading the sound for the first time is what causes the lag.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a mp3 link device needs to download file before playing it, so the lag. if you want to play music without lag you need streaming media.

Wowza server allows you to setup streaming media using m3u8 (HLS) protocol.